# How do you create a dummy event in Gtk?

Tags: c, event-handling, gtk

In a Gtk-based UI there is some code that will run after every user event. I want to skip directly to that code, as if a user event had occurred, something similar to `PostMessage(hwndframe, WM_NOTIFY, 0, 0)` in Windows.

I have been able to achieve this using a [very short timer with an empty callback function](https://github.com/garglk/garglk/blob/master/garglk/sysgtk.c#L93-L108) as a "dummy event," but it feels pretty hacky. Basically I'd like to know the proper way to do this.

I tried using `g_idle_add()` instead of `g_timeout_add()`, but it would only work once, and would hang on the subsequent call.